# PySpark failing to Import collect_list, the functions no collect_list WHY?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use `collect_list` in:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
```

But functions package has no `collect_list` just `_collect_list_doc`

[image: pyspark 2.3.0 version]

Answer (score 0):

Import functions from sql like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

Then you can use F.collect_set("field_name")

Comment: It's dosen't work, but I found out how to achieve，just need to use `collect_list` directly in the sql statement to take effect without `import`